# SEO webmaster sitelinks issue

Tags: seo

I get sitelinks when I type the whole domain – eg: domain.com
But the sitelinks does not show up when only domain is typed. What could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no issues, such situations happens when your website is new, or if is not so popular on search engines. I have come across such situations multiple times with my client website. Do some online promotion for your website. Once your website starts getting decent traffic, the sitelinks will start showing up, on typing domian name only.